# How to reset the first dropdownlist when greater than second dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdown list. Below is the code for two dropdownlists.

```
<select id="SearchForm_min_cost_select" style="display: none;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1lakh">1lakh</option>
    <option value="2lakh">2lakh</option>
    <option value="3lakh">3lakh</option>
    <option value="4lakh">4lakh</option>
    <option value="5lakh">5lakh</option>
    <option value="6lakh">6lakh</option>
</select>
</br>
<select id="SearchForm_max_cost_select" style="display: none;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1lakh">1lakh</option>
    <option value="2lakh">2lakh</option>
    <option value="3lakh">3lakh</option>
    <option value="4lakh">4lakh</option>
    <option value="5lakh">5lakh</option>
    <option value="6lakh">6lakh</option>
</select>
```

I created a dependent dropdown using the below jQuery code and works fine. This function is called in min

```
<script>
function cost_change(price) {
    var removed;

    var match = <?php echo json_encode( Yii::app()->params['match_resales']);?>;

    console.log("match",match);

    var value = match[price];

    console.log("value",value);         

    jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html( jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').html())     
    jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').prepend(removed);

    var toKeep = jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value) > parseInt( price);       
    });        

    console.log("to keep",toKeep);

    removed =  jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value) < parseInt( price);
    });

    jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html(toKeep);
}
</script>
```

Now when I select max value in second dropdownlist less than min value in first dropdownlist the value of first dropdownlist should reset equal to second. Suppose I select 3lakh in min and 2lakh in max the value of min should autoset to 2lakh. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need more logic stimulate the behavior you wanted.

**Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/573Yf/**

```
var i=$('#min'),x=$('#max'),a,b;
$(i).change(function(){
    a=i[0]; b=x[0];
    if(a.selectedIndex>b.selectedIndex) {
        b.selectedIndex = a.selectedIndex;
    }
});
$(x).change(function(){
    a=i[0]; b=x[0];
    if(b.selectedIndex<a.selectedIndex) {
        a.selectedIndex = b.selectedIndex;
    }
});
```